# Unrecognized attribute 'xdt:Transform' in IIS

Tags: web, iis

I hosted a web application in IIS and below is the web.config file for the application, but when i open the application i am getting following error **Unrecognized attribute 'xdt:Transform'**

```
`<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">
    <system.webServer xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
        <rewrite xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
            <rules xdt:Transform="InsertIfMissing">
              <rule name="index.html" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url=".*" />
                <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                  <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" pattern="" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.html" />
              </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>`
```

Comment: Such attributes should have been removed during transformation and not present in the final `web.config` file in deployment.

Comment: Can you work normally locally? or is this error encountered only when hosted on IIS?